# How to kill subprocess if no activity in stdout/stderr

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a program from a python script (currently with `os.system`). However, sometimes the program hangs at a point and I would like to kill it if nothing is written to stdout or stderr after a certain time interval. A simple timeout on the program won't work, because this code typically runs for a very long time (many hours to days), and sometimes it hangs before it still has a long way to go.

It seems that `subprocess.Popen` is the way to go, but I haven't found a good example on how to do this. I also wanted to write the stdout/stderr to a file.

Based on some examples I was thinking about something like this:

```
p = Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    outfile.write(line)
    # save current time or something, compare to time of
    # previous loop, if larger than timeout, kill process
```

But I'm not sure how to implement the time loop, and how to make sure that the `while` doesn't run forever when the process eventually terminates on its own (and doesn't hang). Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not fix the bug in the child process so it doesn't hang?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, yes that is of course the best solution. However, in this case this is a rare occurrence and really hard to replicate. In some cases it also hangs for reasons outside the process (e.g. filesystem, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `signal.alarm` to set a timer after each line is received, and then handle `SIGALRM` by checking if too much time has passed since the last line.

Comment: Thank you. `signal.alarm` is really cool. I managed to implement what I wanted using it.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's the code I ended up using, making use of the suggested `signal.alarm`:

```
import time
import shlex
import subprocess

logfile = open(log, 'w', 1)
# cmd is command to run
args = shlex.split(cmd)   # tokenise args list
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, bufsize=0, stdin=None,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

def _handler(signum, frame):
    print('Timeout of %s min reached, stopping execution' % timeout)
    p.kill()
    time.sleep(30)  # to ensure no ghost process is left running
    raise RuntimeError('Timeout')

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handler)
try:
    while True:
        signal.alarm(int(timeout))
        inline = p.stdout.readline()
        if not inline:
            break
        logfile.write(inline)
        signal.alarm(0)
except RuntimeError:
    logfile.close()
    return 0

p.communicate()   # wait for process to finish, get return code
logfile.close()
return p.returncode
```

Comment: are you sure your code is working? I've tried it but the subprocess is killed immediately.

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes, I've run this regularly for years. Perhaps it is not very portable and doesn't work in all systems? I've run it on Linux and Python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you @tiago, I'll give it a try again.

Comment: Yes, SIGALRM is only available on Unix as per the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGALRM .