# Using subprocess.Popen to start a program in Windows - subprocess sometimes gets stuck - is my script stable?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

As part of my Python (3.8.2) script, I start a program in Windows (10) via command line. This program runs a simulation, exports data, and closes. My script does this hundreds of times. Very occasionally, the cmd window appears but displays nothing (the Windows program does not seem to be doing anything). I am trying to determine whether the problem is with the external program, or my script.

I have searched for other answers but the subprocess world is proving difficult to understand. I use Python for some basic moving/interpreting data. I saw this answer ([Understanding Popen.communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768290/understanding-popen-communicate)), which includes

> Note: it is a very fragile code if read/write are not in sync; it
> deadlocks.

This seems relevant but I am not in a position to understand & implement it.

My function is:

```
def run_program(args):
    cmd = #defined by args
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    variables = #read from some datafiles created by the program that was run
    return variables
```

Is there any clear reason why the subprocess gets stuck? (I don't know if the correct term is blocks or hangs).

Answer (score 0):

A working solution, with inspiration from [How to kill subprocess if no activity in stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461287/how-to-kill-subprocess-if-no-activity-in-stdout-stderr)

```
def run_program(args, timeout):
    cmd = [] #defined by args
    if timeout == 'default':
        timeout = 600
    tries = 0
    while tries < 4:
        tries += 1
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            t = 0
            while p.poll() != 0:
                if t > timeout:
                    raise RuntimeError('Timeout')
                    break
                time.sleep(1)
                t+=1
            successful = True
        except RuntimeError:
            kill = subprocess.Popen("TASKKILL /F /PID {pid} /T".format(pid=p.pid))
            # some actions for this condition
            successful = False
        if successful == True:
            # some actions for this condition
            break
    return variables, t
```

I use the `timeout` variable to pass information about the last run time in/out of the function.